# Laravel: Add route prefix from session variable

Tags: laravel, session, routes, laravel-5

In Laravel 5.2 route file I'm trying to do something like:

```
Route::group('prefix' => Session::get('dataId')], ...
```

however, I noticed that I can't access the session variable from there. 
I don't want to do:

```
Route::group('prefix' => {dataId}], ...
```

because it will take too much time to add it in all the methods in the controllers. 
Any ideas how to achieve this functionality?

**Edit:** tried with middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $request->route()->prefix(Session::get('dataId'));

    return $next($request);
}
```

but when trying to access mysite/dataId it's not found

Comment: could you please explain how you want to use prefix from seesion and why?? and what do you mean by ` too much time to add it in all the methods in the controllers` as prefix will be added on route??

Comment: Yeah a little context might help. Does it have to come from session specifically?

Comment: Maybe Route::group('prefix' => {dataid}, ... )->where('dataid', Session::get('dataId')); or something like that will work?

Comment: With last suggestion throws "Call to a member function where() on null".

Comment: It does not need to come from the session specifically, can load the data from the database, as long as I have the authenticated user.

Comment: you want to prefix {dataId} for all routes..?

Comment: yes, I tried session_start() in RouteServiceProvider, but $_SESSION is empty

Comment: you can get session in middleware handle method and can change the url. It mean you can add prefix here

Comment: @D Coder made middleware with function `code` public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $request->route()->prefix(Session::get('dataId'));

        return $next($request);
    } `code` but when trying to access mysite/dataId it's not found